# Request for a 10K user to review a self deletion

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I saw in my RSS-feed log a question:
[**"How do you make predictions with Mocha"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509868/how-do-you-make-predictions-with-mocha)

And I thought:

> "That is a great question, it is unreasonably hard to make predictions with Mocha. It is not documented, and the package maintainers closed the issue for it not being documented because they felt it obvious. 
>   Luckily for the question asker, I spent several hours working out how last week.
>   I can write a great answer to that question."

But when I went to look at the question, it had been deleted.
Normally I would move on, but this to me is a question I would have loved to have  had answered a week ago.

It may have been deleted as a duplication -- which is wrong, we want to leave duplicates as sign posts.

Or perhaps it got many downvotes for no research, which I can tell you would be unfair.

Or it might have been deleted by the person asking it deleting it because they got their answer.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone with the rep can check it, and make sure it was a reasonable deletion.

Comment: Or was simply unsuitable for the Q&A format...

Comment: @Braiam prediction in neural net terminology does not refer to predicting the future (out of domain prediction), but merely to executing the "predict" action, i.e. a FeedForward pass and then getting the output. Rather than "solve"/"train", which runs feedforward then back propagate on known data. It is actually not a question of philosophy, or even applied statistics/machine learning. Just a question on how the API is structured. It is not fundermentally different to "How do I convert UTF16 to UTF8 in java?".

Comment: It's not something you should be doing all the time, but leave a link to this meta question on something that user has posted, and ask them to undelete the question if they still have a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't look like any of those things happened, the OP just decided to delete the question on their own.

[image: screenshot]

> I spent several hours working out how last week. I can write a great answer to that question. [...] Normally I would move on, but this to me is a question I would have loved to have answered a week ago.

If you think it would make a good Q&A, you can post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I would caution how OP would have worded that question, because that title straight out rings many alarms

Comment: Thanks, I will create a self answer for it. At some point.